# Extraction not empty data featureclass from a workspace by arcpy!

Tags: arcpy, file-geodatabase

What I want from python script,  searching a workspace containing Geodatabases and feature classes(Iterate Feature Classes), then clip those by interested Area (polygon). the resulted clipped files most not empty. I tried to convert Model builder to Python script and added "If" condition to transfer not empty features to final geodatabase:

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
#script arguments
env.workspace=arcpy.GetParameterASText(0)
clip_Features = arcpy.GetParameterASText(1)
FeatureClass_clip = arcpy.GetParameterASText(2)


#Local variables:
Recursive = "true"
Name = "FeatureClass"
Feature_Class = "\\FeatureClass"
FeatureClass_Clip__2_= FeatureClass_clip

FeatureClass = arcpy.ListFeatueClasses("*")
#Process : Clip
arcpy.Clip_analysis(FeatureClass, Clip_Features, FeatureClass_Clip, "")
#Process: Delet Features
for fc in FeatureClass_Clip:
    Count1=str(arcpy.Getcount_managment(fc))
    if count1 <> "0":
       arcpy.FeatureClassToGeodatabase_conversion(FeatureClass_Clip, "")
```

I imported the script to toolbox and defined parameters, but script 
not ran because of clip raise error.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour] to learn about our focused Q&A format.  You say it doesn't work, but haven't included any info about what it does that isn't what you want.  Please [edit] your question to include more detail about what your script does do including any error messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this thing. Here it works with gdb files.
Make two input parameters: the first is *.gbd with feature classes you want to check, the second is clip feature class

```
import arcpy
import  os

from arcpy import env


#script arguments


gdb=arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0) #type - workspace
clip_Features = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1) #type - feature class
out_gdb = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2) #type - workspace


arcpy.env.workspace = gdb


#get feature classes full paths
#this thing will search only for feature classes in the root of gdb file, not in datasets


flist = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses("*")
list_to_clip = flist



#make feature layer of clip feature class


arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(clip_Features ,"clip_layer")


#iterate through feature classes of gdb

for n in list_to_clip:
    in_fc = os.path.join(gdb, n)
    arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(in_fc,"f_layer")
    arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management("f_layer","INTERSECT","clip_layer","","NEW_SELECTION")   

    #check if selection contains features

    check = arcpy.Describe("f_layer")

    if len(check.FIDset)!=0:

        out_fc = os.path.join (out_gdb, (n + '_clipped'))

        # at this moment you can do whatever you want with your selection, i.e. clip, copy, convert

        arcpy.Clip_analysis("f_layer","clip_layer",out_fc)
        arcpy.AddMessage("Layer "+ n + " clipped")

        arcpy.Delete_management("f_layer")



    else:
        arcpy.Delete_management("f_layer")
```

**UPDATE:** to use script with output gdb:

Added these strings:

```
out_gdb = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2) #type - workspace
```

Changed the process of making feature layers: 
input layer:

```
for n in list_to_clip:
    in_fc = os.path.join(gdb, n)
    arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(in_fc,"f_layer")
```

output feature class (calculated with gdb set by user in [2] parameter):

```
out_fc = os.path.join (out_gdb, (n + '_clipped'))
```

changed method of calculating the selection (len("f_layer") will give the exact number of features in feature class if they are not selected):

```
check = arcpy.Describe("f_layer")

    if len(check.FIDset)!=0:
```

Comment: I think script needs a destination geodatabase to get as parameter! how can I re struct the script to transfer clipped feature classes to a new geodatabase?

Comment: @J.Sobhan sorry for long answer, check the code above I made some corrections, now you can use it with output gdb. Relace the text and add a parameter like Output GDB in Script Properties.

Comment: @  Pavel Pereverzev, I appreciate your attention and time to my question. I converted the script to the tool but an error happened " clip feature dataset exists!  ..." I changed source workspace, clip feature, and output workspace,  the error still persists.

Comment: @J.Sobhan you mean you converted it into pythonaddin tool or what exactly?

Comment: @J.Sobhan well, this script is made for *.gdb bases with feature classes. You can try to change type of `arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)` to "Folder" and loop through shapefiles in folder

Comment: @ Pavel, I changed my computer and repeated the procedure, script well done. Thanks a lot !!  the only problem is about searching folder and subfolders (recursive). this script ran just for a folder containing shapefiles that I can solve it by model builder iterating workspace.